# Internal working of Hashing. put and get method implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I am familiar with How HashMap works and key-value concept.

I know HashCode method generates hashcode based on address of Object and key passed.

But I want to know how it does insertion and search in constant time i.e. O(1)

I need to know in detail what actually happens when I call the put() method and get() method. What is that hashcode value which is giving me power of fetching value in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

The `hashCode` can be computed in O(1) time, and based on the `hashCode` you are mapped to an index of an array. Each index of the array contains a linked list of entries whose keys were mapped to the same index (or bucket). The map is maintained in a way that keeps the average number of elements in each linked list constant, which means it takes O(1) time to locate an entry in the HashMap based on the `hashCode` of its key.

Comment: "based on the hashCode you are mapped to an index of an array." Are you saying, we store hashcode value and respective index mapping somewhere and if yes, which collection are we using? If no, then how are we doing mapping.

Comment: @user1140840 I'm not saying we store the and index. The `hashCode` value may be cached by the class of the key (for example, the String class caches the hashCode of the String, since String is immutable, so there's no need to calculate it more than once). The index is calculated based on the hashCode value each time you call get() or put() or containsKey(). The mapping is a function being applied on the hashCode value in addition to applying modulus to the result, in order to get an index within the range of the array.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not in sync with you on "index is calculated" term. I assume index of array is predefined and that predefined index is mapped to a unique 'hashcode' . Also, I've no idea on how hashcode is getting cached or mapped. Can you share some link or explain things with a little detail. Thanks!

Comment: @user1140840 In java 6, the index for a given key is calculated by `hash(key.hashCode())% table.length` where hash is the method `hash(int h) {h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12); return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);}` and `table` is the array the contains the buckets. Note that when the capacity of the HashMap is increased, table.length grows, so the index of a specific key can change. Also note that different hashCode may be mapped to the same index of the array.